# When to perform additional processing on the form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm writing a form where some additional processing is required before sending the values. The image below depicts the simplified example.

[image]

where `test_date` and `remind_date` are saved on the server as a string of format `YYYY/MM/DD`. 
However, the text field shown above allows users to enter an integer. The value from this field needs to be processed (basically, `test_date - form_value`).

I'm currently doing this conversion before sending the value to the server, within a `saveForm()` function that is triggered when the Submit button is pressed.

I feel like this might not be the ideal way, and wanted to get your opinions. Would it be better to handle this within the controller, by allowing a new param?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple field like this you can just create another instance variable in the controller.

For more complex calculations or additional fields you could use a form object, eg: using the https://github.com/andypike/rectify gem or Reform.